# Karate - driver.intercept : Unknown identifier: intercept

Tags: karate

I am using the latest version of karate (1.1.0).
My scenario is shown down

```
Feature: Public Screen

  Background:


  Scenario: API login with KeyClock
    * driver baseUrl + '/public/dashboard'
    * waitFor('#root > div > div.css-1lr4xv1 > header > div.css-k008qs > div.css-70qvj9 > button').click()
    * waitForUrl(keycloakUrl)
    * input('#username', '#######')
    * input('#password', '#######')
    * driver.intercept({ patterns: [{ urlPattern: 'http://bkr.qa.proxym-it.tn/?session_state=*&code=*' }], mock: 'mock-02.feature' })
    * click('#kc-login')
```

and the error is

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: js failed:
>>>>
01: driver.intercept({ patterns: [{ urlPattern: 'http://bkr.qa.proxym-it.tn/?session_state=*&code=*' }], mock: 'mock-02.feature' })
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (intercept) on com.intuit.karate.driver.chrome.ChromeWebDriver@661744e8 failed due to: Unknown identifier: intercept
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works only for driver type `chrome`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#driverintercept

If you are still stuck follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Yes , my driver is chrome but not still working